# Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I am new to Symfony2, and I am not getting any answer for this error message

```
Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?
```

My version of Symfony is 2.3

I go such code in my Controller addAction()

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $user = new User(); //User is my main entity
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('company','entity', array(
            'class' => 'AGUserBundle:Company', //OneToMany child entity with User
            'property' => 'name',
            'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->getForm();

    $form->add('Ajouter', 'submit', array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'),
    ));


    $request = $this->get('request');

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

I have an User class that have a OneToMany relationship with my Company class, everything is correctly generated by Doctrine.

My goal is to make a user creation form with the current list of Companies, to allow user to pick one and link it to his account.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually I am able to avoid this error by using a formType hierarchy, but when I post the form, symfony wants to add a new Company, instead of updating my User with the company that I have chosen. Any way to do what I need?

Comment: OneToMany would mean that a `User` could be enlisted with multiple companies. I believe you should try it the other way around. A `ManyToOne` relationship `User` <-> `Company`. That way you can assign a single company to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Andariel, my relation was wrong (need a ManyToOne)

For my second issue, I was able to register the user using the userManager of FOSUserBundle and it worked like a charm.

Here is the code if it can help someone :

```
 if($form->isValid()){
        //Getting the company from FORM Response
        $companyObject = $form->getData()->getCompany(); 

        //Setting company to user Obj
        $user->setCompany($companyObject); 

        //Persisting changes
        $userManager->updateUser($user,false);

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
            'notice',
            'User added !'
        );

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_list'));
    }
```